# Symfony2 how to inject UserProviderInterface into service? (or correct way of injecting UserRepository into UserProvider)

Tags: security, symfony

I developing own User Provider. For retrieving User I have injected my UserRepository:

```
app_bundle.api_key_user_provider:
    class: AppBundle\Security\User\ApiKeyUserProvider
    factory: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "getRepository"]
    arguments:
        - AppBundle\Entity\User
```

I also added EntityManager into `__construct()` method of my provider:

```
class ApiKeyUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($email)
    {
        $user = $this->em->findBy(array('email' => $email));

        if (!$user) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException('User not found!');
        }

        $this->user = $user;

        return $user;
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $user;
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class === 'AppBundle\Entity\User';
    }
}
```

But when Provider is called, I got next error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider::__construct()
>   must implement interface
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface, instance
>   of AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository given

I have tried to inject `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface`, but have no success. I pass as argument to `services.yml` provider definition next strings:

1. Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface (got error "class not exists")
2. Vendor\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface (got same error)

Also I've searched for needed service in SecurityBundle, but found nothing.

**My question**: How can I inject `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface` to my `ApiKeyUserProvider` or what else I can do to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: ApiKeyUserProvider implements the UserProviderInterface?

Comment: @Matteo yes, implements

Comment: I have added my UserProvider class to my question.

Comment: If I correctly understand, The ApiKeyUserProvider IS your UserProvider,  try  define it in the service.yml as simple IOC without the factory definition. Otherwise i don't understand your situation (what are you looking for? Probably i miss a piece in your application...)

Comment: @Matteo you understand me correctly, `ApiKeyUserProvider` is my own UserProvider. I want to inject `UserRepository` into it instead of injecting entire entity manager. I think it's possible. So I try to find the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ApiKeyUserProvider` expects EntityManager as a dependency. Your service definition is wrong in that case - just put this into services.yml

```
app_bundle.api_key_user_provider:
    class: AppBundle\Security\User\ApiKeyUserProvider
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

This will also need some adjustments in your class, since `EntityManager` does not have `findBy` method as you're trying to use it. So you need to change

```
$user = $this->em->findBy(array('email' => $email));
```

into

```
$user = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findBy(array('email' => $email));
```

**EDIT:** Basing on your comment I assume that you want to inject `UserRepository`, not whole `EntityManager`. To do so, you should define your `UserRepository` as a service and inject it into your class.

**services.yml**

```
app_bundle.user_repository:
    class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
    factory: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", getRepository]
    arguments:
        - AppBundle\Entity\User

app_bundle.api_key_user_provider:
    class: AppBundle\Security\User\ApiKeyUserProvider
    arguments: ["@app_bundle.user_repository"]
```

**ApiKeyUserProvider**

```
class ApiKeyUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(UserRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($email)
    {
        $user = $this->repository->findBy(array('email' => $email));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. Can you please explain me, why my service definition is wrong, when error says that `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface` just need to be passed as first argument?

Comment: constructor of your class expects to receive ``EntityManager`` which does not match your service definition. Moreover your error message is related to ``DaoAuthenticationProvider`` which has nothing to do with code you provided us with - which makes me think that there might be some other issues than service definition - but this definition is wrong

Comment: well, your solution is working, so +1. I will accepted it later, if not found other solution.

Comment: check my edit regarding injecting ``UserRepository``, not whole ``EntityManager``

Comment: yeah! same solution I have found few minutes ago (https://gist.github.com/webdevilopers/5b0e90031b6a0c5da3bc#file-services-yml). Thanks a lot!